# Firefox live http headers, curley braces after Cache-Control: no-cache

Tags: php, javascript

I'm setting up a php cURL script to replicate what I'm seeing in the live headers.
this is an example.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
{"username":"me@mydomain.com","password":"mypass","namespaceId":"50000003"}
```

They use javaScript to log users in and I have never seen this before.
Typically if there are cookies or form data transmitted it is noted in the header.

How would I send that with cURL?

If you open up live http headers and visit [this URL](https://merchantcenter.intuit.com/msc/portal/login), enter an invalid username and pass you will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this class that i wrote can help you

```
 function HeaderProc($response,$Run="",$String=1/*[Is 1 IF Use for String Mode ]*/){
          print_r($response);
          if($String==1){
             $response=explode("\r\n",$response);  
          }
          $PartHeader=0;
          $out[$PartHeader]=array();
          while(list($key,$val)=each($response)){
              $name='';
              $value='';
              $flag=false;
              for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);$i++){
                  if($val[$i]==":"){
                      $flag=true;
                      for($j=$i+1;$j<strlen($val);$j++){
                        if($val[$i]=="\r" and $val[$i+1]=="\n"){    
                            break;
                        }
                        $value.=$val[$j];
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                  $name.=$val[$i]; 
              }
              if($flag){
                if($name=='' and $value==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                  if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){
                    if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                    }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$value;  
                    }
                  }else{
                    $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$value;
                  }
                }
              }else{
                if($name==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                    if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){ 
                      if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                      }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$name;  
                      }
                    }else{
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$name; 
                    }
                } 
              }
              if($Run!=""){
                $Run($name,$value);  
              }
          }
          return $out;
}

 class cURL { 
    var $headers; 
    var $user_agent; 
    var $compression; 
    var $cookie_file; 
    var $proxy; 
    var $Cookie; 
    function CookieAnalysis($Cookie){//convert str cookie to array cookie 
       //echo $Cookie;
       $this->Cookie=array();
       preg_replace_callback("~(.*?)=(.*?);~si",function($m){$this->Cookie[trim($m[1])]=trim($m[2]);},' '.$Cookie.'; ');
       return $this->Cookie;
    }
    function cURL($cookies=false,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') {
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'; 
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
         $this->headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
         $this->user_agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (SepidarSoft [Organic Search Engine Crawler] Linux Edition) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5';
         $this->compression=$compression; 
         $this->proxy=$proxy; 
         $this->cookies=$cookies; 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
    } 
    function cookie($cookie_file) { 
         if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
         } else { 
            fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
            @fclose($this->cookie_file); 
         } 
    }
    function GET($url) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         $response = curl_exec($process);
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function POST($url,$data) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         $response = curl_exec($process); 
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function error($error) { 
         echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b><br>$error</div></center>";
         die; 
    } 
 }
```

sample:

```
  $cc = new cURL(); 
  print_r( $cc->POST('http://www.domain.com','username=me@mydomain.com;password=mypass;namespaceId=50000003"'));
```

for old php

```
function HeaderProc($response,$Run="",$String=1/*[Is 1 IF Use for String Mode ]*/){
          if($String==1){
             $response=explode("\r\n",$response);  
          }
          $PartHeader=0;
          $out[$PartHeader]=array();
          while(list($key,$val)=each($response)){
              $name='';
              $value='';
              $flag=false;
              for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);$i++){
                  if($val[$i]==":"){
                      $flag=true;
                      for($j=$i+1;$j<strlen($val);$j++){
                        if($val[$i]=="\r" and $val[$i+1]=="\n"){    
                            break;
                        }
                        $value.=$val[$j];
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                  $name.=$val[$i]; 
              }
              if($flag){
                if($name=='' and $value==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                  if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){
                    if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                    }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$value;  
                    }
                  }else{
                    $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$value;
                  }
                }
              }else{
                if($name==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                    if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){ 
                      if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                      }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$name;  
                      }
                    }else{
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$name; 
                    }
                } 
              }
              if($Run!=""){
                $Run($name,$value);  
              }
          }
          return $out;
}

class cURL { 
    var $headers; 
    var $user_agent; 
    var $compression; 
    var $cookie_file; 
    var $proxy; 
    var $Cookie; 
    function CookieAnalysis($Cookie){//convert str cookie to array cookie 
       //echo $Cookie;
       $this->Cookie=array();
       preg_match("~(.*?)=(.*?);~si",' '.$Cookie.'; ',$M);
       $this->Cookie[trim($M[1])]=trim($M[2]);
       return $this->Cookie;
    }
    function cURL($cookies=false,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') {
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'; 
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
         $this->headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
         $this->user_agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (SepidarSoft [Organic Search Engine Crawler] Linux Edition) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5';
         $this->compression=$compression; 
         $this->proxy=$proxy; 
         $this->cookies=$cookies; 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
    } 
    function cookie($cookie_file) { 
         if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
         } else { 
            fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
            @fclose($this->cookie_file); 
         } 
    }
    function GET($url) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         $response = curl_exec($process);
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           if(!is_array($HeaderP['Set-Cookie']))continue;
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function POST($url,$data) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         $response = curl_exec($process); 
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
            if(!is_array($HeaderP['Set-Cookie']))continue;
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function error($error) { 
         echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b><br>$error</div></center>";
         die; 
    } 
 }
```

sample:

```
  $cc = new cURL(); 
  print_r( $cc->POST('http://www.domain.com','username=me@mydomain.com;password=mypass;namespaceId=50000003"'));
```

Comment: Thanks, mohammad.
I tried posting the data as you have it formatted but it didn't work.
In youre code, I'm having problems with preg_replace_callback complaining about {.
Checked with php.net and changed it to create_function and not sure how curley braces come into play here.
I think you are on the right track. but I just can't work out the logic of preg_replace_callback.

Comment: @LorenWolsiffer problem for T-function accord when your php version is before 5.3.8 best solution is upgrade php, or define function as normal function then put function name in preg_replace_callback see answer

Comment: I will accept your answer but the solution came when I added this.

Comment: oops

    $header[] = "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8";

and

    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,"; 
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,application/json,text/javascript,*/*;q=0.01";