# Detecting redirected Google Maps place_id via API

Tags: google-places-api

I'm looking for a way to determine if a `place_id` and the Google Maps URL obtained by firing a details request for that `place_id` to the Google Places API Web Service is being redirected to another Google Maps result.

I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297000/get-redirected-url-from-url) about getting the redirected Photo URL would be relevant, but it appears to be behavior different than what I'm seeing.

Here goes:

**The Good Listing**

Place ID: `ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARm-54MM1clQE` represents a listing with the following NAP:

- Full House Casino Events
- 17941 Sky Park Cir Suite B, Irvine, CA 92614, USA
- (949) 439-5207

Its Maps ID is [114099401919098523](https://maps.google.com/?cid=114099401919098523). Visiting that URL on Google Maps returns me a listing with the same NAP as the API details request.

**The Redirected Listing**

Place ID: `ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARv0ORjjGlaFg` represents a listing with the following NAP:

- Full House Casino Events
- **24752 Cutter, Laguna Niguel, CA 92677, USA**
- (949) 439-5207

Note that the name and phone are the same as the first `place_id`

**NOTE:** *The API HTTP response returns a `200` (not a `30x`) with the same ID as the one requested. So this rules out following a redirect or checking for a different ID in the reply.*

Its Maps ID is [6370523305179431871](https://maps.google.com/?cid=6370523305179431871). Visiting that URL on Google Maps redirects me to a listing with a *different* address as the details API request.

Moreover, it has been redirected to the first listing pointed out above.

From the consumer's perspective, this makes sense because the latter is likely a duplicate of the former, and has been merged to send user traffic in the browser to the correct location.

**The Question**

How would I determine this programmatically? I have stepping through the redirects one by one using `curl`. However, the IDs end up getting mangled into some encoded hex value that I don't understand how to parse yet.

If there isn't some feasible way to determine this other than checking the resulting listing in the browser, I might check with the Google Maps team to see what they suggest.

Thanks for any approach you might have to suggest, or clarity you can offer on the relationship among `place_ids` and Google Maps IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE(2016-09-19):** This issue is fixed in Places API now: a Details request for The Redirected Listing (`ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARv0ORjjGlaFg`) returns The Good Listing (`ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARm-54MM1clQE`)

Previously, redirected places would show up [in the Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsResults) with a flag:

```
permanently_closed: true
```

There is a feature request to [Add redirecting Place or Maps ID in "Place Details" request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10394) that you may be interested in. If so, star it to receives updates.

If you're curl-downloading URLs from Google Maps (not the API) and relying on HTTP redirects... well, that's bound to change at any unpredictable time, I'd recommend very much against it.

Comment: This issue is fixed in Places API now: a Details request for The Redirected Listing (ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARv0ORjjGlaFg) returns The Good Listing (ChIJF07Dwbbv3IARm-54MM1clQE)